# How do scholarly Greek lexicons inform our view of the translation of the Greek phrase "σῶμα ψυχικόν" at 1 Corinthians 15:44?

Tags: 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 15:44 (GNT):

> 44. σπείρεται **σῶμα ψυχικόν**, ἐγείρεται σῶμα πνευματικόν. ἔστι σῶμα ψυχικόν, καὶ ἔστι σῶμα πνευματικόν.

1 Corinthians 15:44 Latin Vulgate:

> 44. seminatur **corpus animale** surgit corpus spiritale si est corpus animale est et spiritale sic et scriptum est

1 Corinthians 15:44 (DRB):

> It is sown a **natural body,** it shall rise a spiritual body. If there be a natural body, there is also a spiritual body, as it is written:

What is the accurate translation of "σῶμα ψυχικόν"?

What is the accurate translation of "corpus animale"?

I looked many variations of this phrase, like:

- natural body.
- physical body.
- animal body. Weymouth New Testament.

Thus, what is the accurate translation of "σῶμα ψυχικόν"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the clear distinctions made in the NT is between the natural life, or fleshly life (before conversion) on the one hand, and the spiritual life on the other hand (after conversion).

This distinction is seen several times and is often described (in overly) literal terms as:

- psychical; that is natural or fleshly body, ie, carnal human passions;
- Spiritual; that is a life controlled by the Holy Spirit

Exactly this distinction is made in the following verses: 1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18.

It might surprise some to learn that the Greek word translated "soul" (ψυχή = psuché) actually means "natural" quite often as listed above (See also BDAG).  This is presumably on the basis of Gen 2:7 which describes the creation of Adam as: "Then the LORD God formed man from the dust of the ground and breathed the breath of life into his nostrils, and the man became a living being" (literally "soul").  Thus, a soul is a person (see also Gen 46:26, 27, Ex 1:5, Josh 10:30, 11:11, Acts 27:37, etc.)

Therefore, in 1 Cor 15:44, most versions have translated correctly as "natural body" or equivalent.  The Latin "corpus animale" is equivalent.

Comment: the soulish is unnatural. Unspiritual=unnatural. Soulish person=psychic person=unnatural person.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is the nature and composition of human bodies resurrected to heaven and how does it differ from our human bodies?

**1 Corinthians 15** defines the heavenly nature and **contrasts** it with the earthly body of humans who are descended from Adam.   The contrast is instructive.  This is seen by looking at **1 Corinthians 15:46-50**

**[1 Corinthians 15:46-50](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A46-50&version=KJV) King James Version (KJV)**

> 46 Howbeit that was not first which is **spiritual**, but that which is **natural**; and afterward that which is **spiritual**. 47 The first man is **of the earth, earthy**; the second man is the Lord **from heaven**. 48 As is the** earthy**, such are they also that are earthy: and as is **the heavenly**, such are they also that are heavenly. 49 And as we have borne the image of the earthy, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly. 50 Now this I say, brethren, that **flesh and blood** cannot inherit the kingdom of God; neither doth corruption inherit incorruption

“Heavenly,” is the  Greek term οὐρανός.
Both **BDAG** [a]  and **Thayer** [b] say the **heavenly**  body of Christ is a nature **contrasted** with dust like Adam.:

The human body we inherited from Adam is composed, “made of dust”, Greek  χοϊκός, as defined by BDAG. [c]

Thayer concurs and says of the pre resurrection body that it is “made of earth.” [d]

The contrast is clearly shown at **1 Corinthians 15:44**:

> 44 it is sown a natural body; it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual (πνευματικόν) body.

The description that directly follows clearly says that the “natural body” is “made of dust” in contrast to the spiritual body that is of a “heavenly nature” [b]

The proper translation must reflect these differences.   If  “natural body”  or “physical body” is interpreted as being differentiated by **composition** from the “spiritual” or “heavenly” body, either translation is acceptable.

In addition,  the verses that precede verse 50 inform our view that “flesh and blood” is the physical earthly body made of dust.

---

[a] BDAG  **οὐρανός**, οῦ, ὁ 24:31 (Hom.+; ‘heaven’ in various senses) … b. Christ is ἐξ οὐρανοῦ  from heaven, of a heavenly nature 1 Co 15:47.

[b] **Thayer**, page 247, **"επουρανιος**  prop. existing in or above heaven, heavenly; 1. existing in heaven ... the heavenly beings, the inhabitants of heaven ... **2. of heavenly origin and nature: 1Co. xv. 48 sq. (opp to χοικος [dust])**; ... Heb. vi. 4. "

[c] BDAG  **χοϊκός**, ή, όν (Rhet. Gr. I 613,   τούτους τοῦ χοϊ κοῦ βάρους; Hesych.; Suda) **made of earth/dust (χοῦς), earthy** ὁ πρῶτος ἄνθρωπος ἐκ γῆς χοϊκός 1 Cor 15:47 (cp. Gen 2:7 ἔπλασεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν ἄνθρωπον χοῦν ἀπὸ τῆς γῆς; SibOr 8, 445 of Adam, χοϊκῷ πλασθέντι; GNaass 252, 59.—Philo, Leg. All. 1, 31 differentiates the οὐράνιος fr. the γήϊνος ἄνθρωπος).—Vss. 48; 49.—DELG s.v.χέω. M-M. TW

[d] **Thayer** χοϊκός, χοικη χοικον (χοῦς, which see), **made of earth**, earthy: **1 Cor. 15:47-49**. (γυμνοί τούτους τοῦ χοϊκοῦ βαρους, Anon. in Walz, Rhett. i., p. 613, 4; (Hippolytus haer. 10, 9, p. 314, 95).)*

Answer (score -1):

**It is sown a soulish body, it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a soulish body, there is also a spiritual one.**

I know of at least one. I entered my favorite's (above) on MSN search and encountered, so far, three others (it's the first time I ever looked at 'em):

https://goedbericht.nl/english/1-corinthians-1544-a-soulish-body/
http://www.askelm.com/news/n050427.htm
https://www.raystedman.org/new-testament/1-corinthians/the-new-body-what-is-it-like

Comment: I grant that you found others who have made this mistake. I checked the BDAG and a couple other lexicons, and none of them had this as a meaning. The error is to assume that a word derives it meaning directly from it root. For example, "anaginosko" is a compound of above/again and know/understand. However, it doesn't mean "know from above" or "know again;" it means "read."

Comment: Thanks. Your error, if you make one, may be to assume that the Greek adjective is **not** derived from, or translatable with, this Greek noun or root. Myself I'm less interested in what Fred Danker, Walter Bauer, or "well-known translations" may say than **why** they say it. "Soulish" is an easy nonesoteric word. I'm searching for its first use in English history. It's a more literal translation than "natural;" and, I feel, connects more precisely with the Bible's careful nouns of our creation and salvation: "spirit, soul, body; regeneration, transformation..." Also, living languages develop.

Answer (score -3):

Look at [Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/15-44.htm). Most of the translations have *natural body*, some have *physical body*. I didn't see any of the variations you suggested.

Google Translate shows *natural* for the Latin *animale*, but Latin *animal* translates to *animal*. I think you misunderstood the Latin word, which led you to *animal body*.

Comment: Weymouth New Testament: animal body. I said: animal body **may be** accepted, not **surely** accepted.

Comment: You're right; I missed that one. The lexicons note that animals have souls, so "animal" could be used in a paraphrase. However, you said, "I think all of them are inaccurate," and that's were I disagree with your question.